# How to imwrite actual GaussianBlur in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

I use the following code to take an original image and blur it:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cv::Mat img  = cv::imread("lenna_orig.png");
    cv::Mat gray, blurred;
    cv::cvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::GaussianBlur(gray, blurred, cv::Size(21, 21), 2.0);
    cv::imwrite("lenna_blur.png", blurred);
    return 0;
}
```

But is there a way to save the actual image of the Gaussian blur? something like this?

```
cv::imwrite("gauss.png", cv::GaussianBlur(cv::Size(21, 21), 2.0));
```

I ask because I eventually want to do a deconvolution problem and compared the computed kernel with the actual Gaussian kernel, so I need to know what the actual Gaussian kernel looks like exactly

EDIT:

I see that if I try

```
cv::Mat g = cv::getGaussianKernel(15, 2.0, CV_64F);
cv::imshow("g", g);
cv::imwrite("g.bmp", g);
```

this won't work because this returns a 15x1 matrix as the kernel, according to the docs. But I want a 15x15 kernel

Comment: Do you see any overload of `cv::GaussianBlur` in the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaabe8c836e97159a9193fb0b11ac52cf1) that returns a `cv::Mat`? (and if you don't trust the docs, the code is on GitHub) What's the problem with the first bit of code you show?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the first bit of code. I just want to also be able to use `imwrite` on the GaussianBlur, but I don't know how

Comment: see my EDIT, I can't get the Gaussian blur to show up

Comment: You might want to edit the title of your question, because right now it's rather misleading -- you don't want to show the blurred image, you want to examine the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cv::getGaussianKernel` returns a 1d Gaussian profile. Since the kernel is symmetric it only needs to calculate a 1d curve.

If you want a 2d version you could stack 15 rows of the 1d ones and then  multiply each column by the same profile.

edit: eg. Suppose the Gaussian kernel was  0.2, 0.4, 1.0, 0.4, 0.2 (simplified version for less typing)

Create the square array, with each row equal to the profile.

`0.2 0.4 1.0 0.4 0.2
 0.2 0.4 1.0 0.4 0.2
 0.2 0.4 1.0 0.4 0.2
 0.2 0.4 1.0 0.4 0.2
 0.2 0.4 1.0 0.4 0.2`

Now multiply each column by the same profile

`0.2
 0.4
 1.0
 0.4
 0.2`

To get something like

`0.04  0.08  0.2  0.08  0.04
 0.08  0.16  0.4  0.16  0.08
 0.2   0.4   1.0  0.4   0.2
 0.08  0.16  0.4  0.16  0.08
 0.04  0.1   0.2  0.08  0.04`

Only with the actual Gaussian profile and a 15x15 result.

ps this demonstrates an important feature of these kernels - they are [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter). That means you can apply them in the x and y directions independently and then combine the result which makes it a lot more efficient to use.

Comment: What do you mean multiply each column by the same profile?

Comment: `cv::GaussianBlur` returns `void`, and the only output parameter AFAIK is the blurred image. Perhaps you, like the OP, are talking about `cv::getGaussianKernel`? (The rest of the text seems to match that)